# how to save every LIST in parallel as a fields and records to the txt file in a clear formatted way in python

Tags: list, file, parallel-processing, field, records

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

SS2=[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 5)]

SS3=[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

I'm Writing my list into a file using the below codes...But when i write again it's adding to the last line of the file.

but what i want is....it should append horizontally not vertically. I mean must go like table and fields and records.

so, for the above `ss1` the line of records is going to be 6 and for every save should add the values in parallel as table fields and records manner

> ss1                 ss2         ss3 
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5      1, 2, 3, 4    1, 2, 3

```
def write_to_txt(a, file_name, delimiter=','):
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        for k in SS1:
            fmt = '%s' % delimiter
            f.write(fmt.join(map(str, k)) + '\n')
```

not only writing and help me to read it back to same number of lists based on it's number columns.

```
def read_from_txt(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        data = [tuple(map(int, k.split(','))) for k in f.read().splitlines()]
    return data

#write_to_txt(SS1, 'ABC.txt')
#data  = read_from_txt('ABC.txt')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good first aproach:

```
SS1=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

SS2=[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 5)]

SS3=[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]

ALL = [SS1,SS2,SS3]

def write_to_txt(a, file_name, delimiter=','):
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        for i, ss in enumerate(SS1):
            if i != 0:
                f.write("\n")
            for ss in ALL:
                fmt = '%s' % delimiter
                f.write(fmt.join(map(str, ss[i])) + ",")

write_to_txt("a","lines.txt")
```

Comment: Wow very nice one bro and working perfect and is it possible that i can add another column in an existing file...i mean in our case is adding another SS4 after we create lines.txt with ss1,ss2,ss3.i can come up from that also no issues...if u can provide that very much appreciated. However ton's of thanks indeed for the solution you have provided so for...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not how text files work. If you wish to append "horizontally", what you really need to do is

1. Read each line of the file
2. Append your new value to each line (by concatenating the old string with a new one)
3. Write each new line of the file (now in write mode, not append). Note that this needs to be to a new file, or you should read your whole file first and overwrite it here.

Hope that helps.